# Insert query throws an arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
insert into SignUpForm 
values ('Torito', 9984537856, 'toritom@gmail.com', 'Torito@123')
```

I am trying to run the above query but it will throw this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Please give me the appropriate solution for this.

I created the table with the following datatypes.

```sql
name varchar(50)
mobile bigint
mail varchar(50) 
password varchar(50)

insert into SignUpForm 
values ('Torito', 9984537856, 'toritom@gmail.com', 'Torito@123')
```

Comment: Hi, could you try to add the mobile number "2147483647" and "2147483648"? To check whether the error is? Also, you could try [decimal or numeric type](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp). For the business logic, why do you use number to for the mobile? I think you should let it NVARCHAR.

Comment: Do not use integer type for a phone number - use a varchar column. And I also hope the *password* is not a plain-text value but a hash.

Comment: Tq i will chech this.

Answer (score 2):

looks like the order of column value not matching with column order present in table.

the values needs to be in order of columns present in your table. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (ID, NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('ID','Name','Email')`
```

try with this, if error persist then need to investigate further..

Comment: Yep, always state the columns in an insert statement.